# scala Either.RightProjection confusion (for comprehension de-sugaring)

Tags: scala, for-loop, monads, either

I can use an `=` in a scala for-comprehension (as specified in section [**6.19** of the SLS](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf)) as follows:

### Option

Suppose I have some function `String => Option[Int]`:

```
scala> def intOpt(s: String) = try { Some(s.toInt) } catch { case _ => None }
intOpt: (s: String)Option[Int]
```

Then I can use it thus

```
scala> for {
   |     str <- Option("1")
   |     i <- intOpt(str)
   |     val j = i + 10    //Note use of = in generator
   |   }
   |   yield j
res18: Option[Int] = Some(11)
```

It was my understanding that this was essentially equivalent to:

```
scala> Option("1") flatMap { str => intOpt(str) } map { i => i + 10 } map { j => j }
res19: Option[Int] = Some(11)
```

That is, the embedded generator was a way of injecting a `map` into a sequence of `flatMap` calls. So far so good.

### Either.RightProjection

**What I actually want to do**: *use a similar for-comprehension as the previous example using the `Either` monad*.

However, if we use it in a similar chain, but this time using the `Either.RightProjection` monad/functor, it doesn't work:

```
scala> def intEither(s: String): Either[Throwable, Int] = 
  |      try { Right(s.toInt) } catch { case x => Left(x) }
intEither: (s: String)Either[Throwable,Int]
```

Then use:

```
scala> for {
 | str <- Option("1").toRight(new Throwable()).right
 | i <- intEither(str).right //note the "right" projection is used
 | val j = i + 10
 | }
 | yield j
<console>:17: error: value map is not a member of Product with Serializable with Either[java.lang.Throwable,(Int, Int)]
              i <- intEither(str).right
                ^
```

The issue has something to do with the function that a right-projection expects as an argument to its `flatMap` method (i.e. it expects an `R => Either[L, R]`). But modifying to not call `right` on the second generator, it still won't compile.

```
scala>  for {
 |        str <- Option("1").toRight(new Throwable()).right
 |        i <- intEither(str) // no "right" projection
 |          val j = i + 10
 |      }
 |      yield j
<console>:17: error: value map is not a member of Either[Throwable,Int]
              i <- intEither(str)
                            ^
```

### Mega-Confusion

But now I get doubly confused. The following works just fine:

```
scala> for {
 |       x <- Right[Throwable, String]("1").right
 |       y <- Right[Throwable, String](x).right //note the "right" here
 |     } yield y.toInt
res39: Either[Throwable,Int] = Right(1)
```

But this does not:

```
scala> Right[Throwable, String]("1").right flatMap { x => Right[Throwable, String](x).right } map { y => y.toInt }
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Either.RightProjection[Throwable,String]
 required: Either[?,?]
              Right[Throwable, String]("1").right flatMap { x => Right[Throwable, String](x).right } map { y => y.toInt }
                                                                                             ^
```

I thought these were equivalent

- What is going on?
- How can I embed an `=` generator in a for comprehension across an `Either`?

Comment: Minor note: You don't need `val ` in the for-comprehension. Just `j = i + 10` works fine. However, I don't see a reason to not put the calculation to the right side of the `yield`: `} yield i + 10`. Similary: In the first map-example, the ` map { j => j }` serves no purpose, and can be left out.

Comment: I would define `intOpt` and `intEither` like this: `def intOpt(s: String) = allCatch opt s.toInt` and `def intEither(s: String) = allCatch either s.toInt` (having done `import scala.util.control.Exception._`).

Comment: @user unknown - this is just an example; in my use case, I do want to embed a `map` in a sequence of `flatMap`s

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fact that you cannot embed the `=` in the for-comprehension is related to [this issue](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5793?focusedCommentId=57583&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-57583) reported by Jason Zaugg; the solution is to Right-bias `Either` (or create a new data type isomorphic to it).

For your mega-confusion, you expanded the for sugar incorrectly. The desugaring of

```
for {
  b <- x(a)
  c <- y(b)
} yield z(c)
```

is

```
x(a) flatMap { b =>
 y(b) map { c =>
  z(c) }}
```

and not

```
x(a) flatMap { b => y(b)} map { c => z(c) }
```

Hence you should have done this:

```
scala> Right[Throwable, String]("1").right flatMap { x => Right[Throwable, String](x).right map { y => y.toInt } }
res49: Either[Throwable,Int] = Right(1)
```

#### More fun about desugaring (the `j = i + 10` issue)

```
for {
  b <- x(a)
  c <- y(b)
  x1 = f1(b)
  x2 = f2(b, x1)
  ...
  xn = fn(.....)
  d <- z(c, xn)
} yield w(d)
```

is desugared into

```
x(a) flatMap { b =>
  y(b) map { c =>
    x1 = ..
    ...
    xn = ..
    (c, x1, .., xn) 
  } flatMap { (_c1, _x1, .., _xn) =>
    z(_c1, _xn) map w }}
```

So in your case, `y(b)` has result type `Either` which doesn't have `map` defined.

Comment: As a work around, I replace 'x = y' in Right-sided for comprehensions with 'x <- Right(y).right'. Not perfect but OK for the rare occurrences I use it.