# Either, Options and for comprehensions

Tags: scala, monads, either

I was coding a for comprehension, and wondered something:

```
def updateUserStats(user: User): Either[Error,User] = for {
  stampleCount <- stampleRepository.getStampleCount(user).right
  userUpdated <- Right(copyUserWithStats(user,stampleCount)).right // ?????????
  userSaved <- userService.update(userUpdated).right
} yield userSaved


def copyUserWithStats(user: User, stamples: Long): User = {
  val newStats = user.userStats.copy(stamples = stamples)
  user.copy(userStats = newStats)
}
```

It seems using copyUserWithStats which does not return an Either can't be used directly in the for comprehension, because it doesn't have the map/flatMap methods.

So I wonder, in this case, it is the appropriate solution to use `Right(copyUserWithStats(user,stampleCount)).right`

It seems to work at least...

By the way, I also tried with Option but it didn't work, can someone explain why?

```
def updateUserStats(user: User): Either[Error,User] = for {
  stampleCount <- stampleRepository.getStampleCount(user).right
  userUpdated <- Some(copyUserWithStats(user,stampleCount))
  userSaved <- userService.update(userUpdated).right
} yield userSaved
```

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a for-comprehension all monads have to be of the same kind. That means you can not mix `RightProjection` and `Option`, because the output has to be an `Either`. This is because the for-comprehension gets translated to a nested flatMap/map construct. Your example would look like this:

```
def updateUserStats(user: User): Either[Error,User] =
  stampleRepository.getStampleCount(user).right.flatMap { stampleCount =>
    Some(copyUserWithStats(user,stampleCount)).flatMap { userUpdated =>
      userService.update(userUpdated).right.map { userSaved =>
        userSaved
      }
    }
  }
```

If we now look at the signature of `RightProjection.flatMap`, which is def
`flatMap[AA >: A, Y](f: (B) ⇒ Either[AA, Y]): Either[AA, Y]`, we see, that the result has to be an `Either`, but `flatMap` of `Option` has the signature `flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ Option[B]): Option[B]`. It returns an `Option` and there is no sane way to translate an `Option` to an `Either`.

**edit**: Following example does not quiet work for `Either`, see link by huynhjl for more information

However you can besides extracting values from monads in a for-comprehension also create variables, so your example could be rewritten as:

```
def updateUserStats(user: User): Either[Error,User] = for {
  stampleCount <- stampleRepository.getStampleCount(user).right
  userUpdated = copyUserWithStats(user,stampleCount)
  userSaved <- userService.update(userUpdated).right
} yield userSaved
```

which saves us an unnecessary allocation and also makes the code more readable.

Comment: You tried creating variables like that? It does not work for me with `Either`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688447/scala-either-rightprojection-confusion-for-comprehension-de-sugaring

Comment: Thanks huynhjl. Honestly I just expected it to work and didn't try it.