# Either monadic operations

Tags: scala, either

I just start to be used to deal with monadic operations.
For the Option type, this Cheat Sheet of Tony Morris helped:
http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/

So in the end it seems easy to understand that:

- map transforms the value of inside an option
- flatten permits to transform `Option[Option[X]]` in `Option[X]`
- flatMap is somehow a map operation producing an `Option[Option[X]]` and then flattened to `Option[X]`

At least it is what I understand until now.

---

For Either, it seems a bit more difficult to understand since Either itself is not right biaised, does not have map / flatMap operations... and we use projection.

I can read the Scaladoc but it is not as clear as the Cheat Sheet on Options.
Can someone provide an Either Sheet Cheat to describe the basic monadic operations?

It seems to me that `Either.joinRight` is a bit like `RightProjection.flatMap` and seems to be the equivalent of `Option.flatten` for Either.

It seems to me that if `Either` was Right biaised, then Either.flatten would be Either.joinRight no?

In this question: [Either, Options and for comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130039/either-options-and-for-comprehensions/16130181#16130181) I ask about for comprehension with Eiher, and one of the answers says that we can't mix monads because of the way it is desugared into map/flatMap/filter.

When using this kind of code:

```
def updateUserStats(user: User): Either[Error,User] = for {
  stampleCount <- stampleRepository.getStampleCount(user).right
  userUpdated <- Right(copyUserWithStats(user,stampleCount)).right
  userSaved <- userService.update(userUpdated).right
} yield userSaved
```

Does this mean that all my 3 method calls must always return `Either[Error,Something]`? 
I mean if I have a method call `Either[Throwable,Something]` it won't work right?

---

**Edit:**
Is Try[Something] exactly the same as a right-biaised Either[Throwable,Something]?

Comment: If you want a right-biased `Either`, I would recommend using `scalaz.\/` instead.

Comment: That's right. However I'm not really fan of `\/` syntax. It seems I could also use this trick to pimp the Either type: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5793?focusedCommentId=57583&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-57583

Comment: You could also simply use `Try`, which is part of the scala 2.10 library, and is right-biased. Though it is not as general because it also fixes the left type to `Throwable`, but this is probably what you want most of the time.

Comment: yes this is why I ask this in the end of my question :) in this case I will probably replace all my Either with Try... Or maybe with Try[Either[Error,Something]] or IO[Either[Error,Something]] -> This will be on another question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Either` was never really meant to be an exception handling based structure.  It was meant to represent a situation where a function really could possible return one of two distinct types, but people started the convention where the left type is a supposed to be a failed case and the right is success.  If you want to return a biased type for some pass/fail type business checks logic, then `Validation` from `scalaz` works well.  If you have a function that could return a value or a `Throwable`, then `Try` would be a good choice.  `Either` should be used for situations where you really might get one of two possible types, and now that I am using `Try` and `Validation` (each for different types of situations), I never use `Either` any more.