# Try[Result], IO[Result], Either[Error,Result], which should I use in the end

Tags: scala, scalaz, either

I'd like to know what should be the signature of my methods so that I handle different kind of failures elegantly.

This question is somehow the summary of many questions I already had about error handling in Scala. You can find some questions here:

- [Throwing exceptions in Scala, what is the "official rule"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886285/throwing-exceptions-in-scala-what-is-the-official-rule)
- [Either, Options and for comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130039/either-options-and-for-comprehensions)
- [Either monadic operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194180/either-monadic-operations)

---

For now, I understand the following:

- Either can be used as a result wrapper for a method call that may fail
- Try is a Right biaised Either on which the failure is a non-fatal exception
- IO (scalaz) helps to build pure methods that handle IO operations
- All 3 are easily usable in a for comprehension
- All 3 are not easily mixable in a for comprehension because of incompatible flatMap methods
- In functional langages we usually don't throw exceptions unless they are fatal
- We should throw exceptions for really exceptional conditions. I guess this is the approach of Try
- Creating Throwables has a performance cost for the JVM and it is not intended to be used for business flow controle

---

**Repository layer**

Now please consider that I have a `UserRepository`. The `UserRepository` stores the users and defines a `findById` method. The following failures could happen:

- A fatal failure (`OutOfMemoryError`)
- An IO failure because the database is not accessible/readable

Additionally, the user could be missing, leading to an `Option[User]` result

Using a JDBC implementation of the repository, SQL, non-fatal exceptions (constraint violation or others) can be thrown so it can make sense to use Try.

As we are dealing with IO operations, then the IO monad also makes sense if we want pure functions.

So the result type could be:

- `Try[Option[User]]`
- `IO[Option[User]]`
- something else?

---

**Service layer**

Now let's introduce a business layer, `UserService`, which provides some method `updateUserName(id,newUserName)` that uses the previously defined `findById` of the repository.

The following failures could happen:

- All repository failures propagated to the Service layer
- Business error: can't update the username of an user that doesn't exist
- Business error: the new username is too short

Then the result type could be:

- `Try[Either[BusinessError,User]]`
- `IO[Either[BusinessError,User]]`
- something else?

BusinessError here is not a Throwable because it is not an exceptional failure.

---

**Using for-comprehensions**

I would like to keep using for-comprehensions to combine method calls.

We can't easily mix different monads on a for-comprehension, so I guess I should have some kind of uniform return type for all my operations right?

I just wonder how do you succeed, in your real world Scala applications, to keep using for-comprehensions when different kind of failures can happen.

For now, for-comprehension works fine for me, using services and repositories which all return `Either[Error,Result]` but all different kind of failures are melted together and it becomes kind of hacky to handle these failures.

Do you define implicit conversions between different kind of monads to be able to use for-comprehensions?

Do you define your own monads to handle failures?

By the way perhaps I'll be using an asynchronous IO driver soon.
So I guess my return type could be even more complicated: `IO[Future[Either[BusinessError,User]]]`

---

Any advice would be welcome because I don't really know what to use, while my application is not fancy: it is just an API where I should be able to make a distinction between business errors that can be shown to the client side, and technical errors. I try to find an elegant and pure solution.

Comment: Could you please post some code some of how you ended up writing this? I am very interested as I have a similar pattern in mind. My scalaz skills are not what I would like them to be... I have a hard time making sense of these classes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is what Scalaz's `EitherT` monad transformer is for.  A stack of `IO[Either[E, A]]` is equivalent to `EitherT[IO, E, A]`, except that the former must be handled as multiple monads in sequence, whereas the latter is automatically a single monad that adds `Either` capabilities to the base monad `IO`.  You can likewise use `EitherT[Future, E, A]` to add non-exceptional error handling to asynchronous operations.

Monad transformers in general are the answer to a need to mix multiple monads in a single `for`-comprehension and/or monadic operation.

---

**EDIT:**

I will assume you are using Scalaz version 7.0.0.

In order to use the `EitherT` monad transformer on top of the `IO` monad, you first need to import the relevant parts of Scalaz:

```
import scalaz._, scalaz.effect._
```

You also need to define your error types:  `RepositoryError`, `BusinessError`, etc.  This works as usual.  You just need to make sure that you can, e.g., convert any `RepositoryError` into a `BusinessError` and then pattern match to recover the exact type of error.

Then the signatures of your methods become:

```
def findById(id: ID): EitherT[IO, RepositoryError, User]
def updateUserName(id: ID, newUserName: String): EitherT[IO, BusinessError, User]
```

Within each of your methods, you can use the `EitherT`-and-`IO`-based monad stack as a single, unified monad, available in `for`-comprehensions as usual.  `EitherT` will take care of threading the base monad (in this case `IO`) through the whole computation, while also handling errors the way `Either` usually does (except already right-biased by default, so you don't have to constantly deal with all the usual `.right` junk).  When you want to do an `IO` operation, all you have to do is raise it into the combined monad stack by using the `liftIO` instance method on `IO`.

As a side note, when working this way, the functions in the `EitherT` companion object can be very useful.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be exactly what I need. Unfortunatly I don't have yet the Scalaz skills to understand how it really works :( Can you please provide a simple exemple of how to use them, using the method signatures I give above?

Comment: @SebastienLorber I have edited my answer to try to explain better.

Comment: @SebastienLorber one Scalaz tip. It's a good idea to try to re-implement a few things by yourself in order to better understand how they work. In this case, implementing the Monad instance for `EitherT` is a really good exercise.

Comment: I get "object effect is not a member of 
  package scalaz" when I do the suggested import.

Comment: @JamesMoore You need to make sure both `scalaz-core` and `scalaz-effect` are on the classpath.

Comment: very nice answer! Is there a simple way to turn a EitherT[IO, E, A] to a IO[Either[E, A]] and use this in the methode signatures?

Comment: @longliveenduro To go from `EitherT[IO, E, A]` to `IO[Either[E, A]]`, use the `toEither` method on your `EitherT` value.  To convert back, use the `fromEither` method on the `EitherT` companion `object`.

Comment: @Ptharien's Flame: Thanks for the hint, I wasn't specific enough. In my solution (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828067/combining-futures-twitter-and-either-in-scala) I use \/ (ScalaZ's Either) and it seems strange that I can only convert the EitherT  to scala.util.Either not back to \/. Do you have an explanation or an easy solution?

Comment: @Ptharien's Flame: I've found it myself: It's called `run`. Wouldn't expect such a method name.

Comment: You can also look at Cats library which has XorT[F[_], A, B] instead of EitherT[F[_], A, B] https://github.com/typelevel/cats

Answer (score 11):

***Update 2 [2020-09]***: there was some evolution in the scala ecosystem since that answer was first redacted. `cat-effect 3` is talking about having a dedicated error channel [update 2021-03: it chose not to do so in the end],  `scalaz 8` stalled, and a new library emerged from it: `ZIO`, a library which has at its core a bi-functor IO monad (+ a dependency injection system, out of the scope of present question), is gaining traction in scala.

As it has a dedicated error channel, just hit v1.0.0, and the topic is still novel, I answered the question (related to this one): [What is ZIO error channel and how to get a feeling about what to put in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63712633/what-is-zio-error-channel-and-how-to-get-a-feeling-about-what-to-put-in-it).

It also deals with more general questions (like: discovering failure modes of application and dealing with them to let futur dev/adminsys/users have agency on behavior, even in case of errors) with a short summary to my [talk systematic error management in application](https://speakerdeck.com/fanf42/systematic-error-management-we-ported-rudder-to-zio). Hope it helps and give more context to that (big and complex) topic.

---

The answer by @pthariens-flame is great, and you should just use it for your task at hand.

I would like to bring some contextual background of recent developments in the domain, so this is just a general information answer.

Error management is basically the #1 work of us, dev. The happy path is happy and boring, and it's not where the user will complain. Most (all?) the problems lies where effects (I/O in particular) are implied in the process.

One of the approach to manage thes problems is to follow what is commonly refered to as a "pure FP approch" where you draw a big red line between pure/total and impure/non-total parts of your programs. When doing so, you leverage the possibility to cleanly deal with errors depending of their kind.

In recent times (18 months?), Scala has seen *a lot* of research and development in that domain. Actually, I believe that Scala is today the most exciting and disrupting place in all languages on that very specific problem (but of course it's likely just a brain bias of availability/recent info).

Scalaz8, Monix and cats-effects are the 3 mains contributors of that fast evolution. So anything related to these 3 projects (conference talk, blog article, etc) will help you understand what is happening.

So, to keep the story short, Scalaz8 will change the way IO is model to better account of error management. John DeGoes is leading the effort here, and he produced some good resources on the subject:

Article:

- No More Transformers: High-Performance Effects in Scalaz 8 http://degoes.net/articles/effects-without-transformers
- Bifunctor IO: A Step Away from Dynamically-Typed Error Handling http://degoes.net/articles/bifunctor-io

Video:

- The Design of the Scalaz 8 Effect System - John A. De Goes https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIPGZzbPpeg

There is also *a lot* of thing going on with Monix and Cats-effect, but I believe that most of the resources on the subject happen in pull requests in corresponding projects.

There is that talk by Alexandru Nedelcu which give some back ground of the problems:

- A Tale of Two Monix Streams https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JFbYQGG2Nb4

And a comparison here by Adam Warski:

- Scalaz 8 IO vs Akka (typed) actors vs Monix (part 1) https://blog.softwaremill.com/scalaz-8-io-vs-akka-typed-actors-vs-monix-part-1-5672657169e1

And finaly, there is excellent article by Luka Jacobowitz for the Cats part: "Rethinking MonadError" https://typelevel.org/blog/2018/04/13/rethinking-monaderror.html which covers a lot of the same ground with an other light.

[Edit]: as noticed by peers, the span of (r)evolution in the domain does not stop to that in scala-land. There is a big work done to try to make effects encoding (IO among other) more performant. The latest steps in the domain are trying to use Kleisli Arrows in place of monads to minimize GC churn on the JVM.

See:

- the first (AFAIK) Scala implementation by TraneIO "Arrows": https://github.com/traneio/arrows
- John DeGoes (again) talk about the subject: https://www.slideshare.net/jdegoes/blazing-fast-pure-effects-without-monads-lambdaconf-2018 and the corresponding PR whose description is insightfull: https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/pull/1857

Hope it helps!

***Update [2018-07]***: there was a long, interesting thread on the subject on reddit: "Can someone explain to me the benefits of IO?" https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/8ygjcq/can_someone_explain_to_me_the_benefits_of_io/

And a contribution by John DeGoes: "Scala Wars: FP-OOP vs FP" http://degoes.net/articles/fpoop-vs-fp

Comment: Wha's the state of art of today when using cats effects IO ?

Comment: AFAIK, cats-effect 3 does not change the general architecture on error management (on the other hand, it's a major evolution regarding fibers).

Comment: Thank you  for this ! There is really a split of philosophy toward error management in the scala fp world ! Zio and cats